# Shaky CSS3 Transition in Google Chrome in ul navigation

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I am creating 2 level navigation with transitions. The issue I am facing is that when dropdown navigation expands it shakes the text in the whole menu. 
I have created a codepen example. The issue seems to happen when I ad transition for transform of the down arrow on services navigation item. If I remove vertical align from .nav class it reduce the shake but it still there.

[Code Pen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNzjrg)

```
.header {
  background: #0c121f;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.header:before, .header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.header:after {
  clear: both;
}

.header-banner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.header-logo, .header-tel {
  display: block;
}

.header-tel {
  height: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 768px) {
  .header-banner {
    height: 9.375rem;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
[class^="ico-"]:before, [class*=" ico-"]:before, [class^="ico-"]:after, [class*=" ico-"]:after {
  font-family: ico;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  line-height: 0.9375rem;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 0.9375rem;
}

.ico-downarrow:before {
  content: "\e007";
}

.ico-downarrow {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.ico-downarrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.nav-wrap {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.nav, .sub-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  z-index: 1000;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  line-height: 0.9375rem;
  height: 3.3125rem;
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #394356;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .nav-wrap {
    height: 9.375rem;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }

  .nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 53.125rem;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .nav-item {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-item:hover {
    background: #394356;
  }

  .sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.3125rem;
    left: 0;
  }

  .sub-nav-item:hover {
    background: #49566f;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .sub-nav {
    max-height: 13.25rem;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .ico-downarrow {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  background: #2c3341;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.3125rem;
  width: 3.3125rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

I check IE and Mozilla works fine. Just Chrome. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own issue thanks for trying if anyone did. I simply used different method for vertically aligning the navigation. So I think the problem is with how chrome renders transform(translateY(-50%)).

```
  .nav {
    height: $nav-item-height;
    width: rem-calc(850); // 850px
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -($nav-item-height/2); // -26.5px
  }
```